High school manhwa/webtoon featuring an unlucky boy with black hair and his red-haired friend; after gaining strange powers, they fight each other
It's about a boy who is unlucky. He has black hair. He also has a friend who has red hair and (I think) a yellow bandana or something on. It's a high school manhwa/webtoon/manhua.
After a good number of chapters, they have some strange powers, and the friends fight. On the fighting day, the atmosphere was dark; it was rainy, etc. I don't know what the webtoon is called. Can someone help me?
I also think the main character has a hard time having friends, but the red-haired one doesn't. 

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions. Also, can you describe the powers of these two characters?

@galacticninja - We have a how-to guide specifically for manga and anime questions also.
